# Concealing \begin and \end lines in latex with MathZone

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, conceal

I'm trying to get the lines that have `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` to be concealed.
I've tried using `call matchadd('Conceal','\\begin{equation\*}', 10,13,{'conceal':' '})` and it works, but it would be nice to change the highlighting of the region, that way the lines will display when the cursor is inside the block.

Then I tried adding `concealends` to the function `TexNewMathZone`, (lines 422 and 432 in `/syntax/tex.vim`) so that they read
`exe 'syn region '.grpname.' start='."'".'\\begin\s*{\s*'.a:mathzone.'\*\s*}'."'".' end='."'".'\\end\s*{\s*'.a:mathzone.'\*\s*}'."'".' concealends contains=@texMathZoneGroup'.foldcmd`

This however doesn't work and the lines aren't concealed. I'd be grateful for any insight.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!